# Multiple foreign key constraints to same table and column fails on update

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb

I've created two tables to do mappings between users. First for users and second for user-mappings. Deletion of users work well, but if I try to update the user id the foreign key constraints from the mapping table fail (without a helpful error output).

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(55),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE user_map (
map_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_a INT,
user_b INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`map_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `one_way` (`user_a`,`user_b`),
  UNIQUE KEY `other_way` (`user_b`,`user_a`),
  CONSTRAINT `acc_connections_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_a`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `acc_connections_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_b`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Example Data:

```sql
INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ("User A");
INSERT INTO user_map (user_a,user_b) VALUES (1,1);
```

If I try to update the user id afterwards I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`test_db`.`user_map`, CONSTRAINT `user_map_ibfk_2`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_b`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

[DB Fiddle (Demo)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=3ec9a7a0dd6bd0d00df8d44cc78351b0)

Interestingly deleting the parent row (user table) succeeds without an error.
What am I doing wrong? I see no reason why this should fail.

Comment: which version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Tested with MySQL 5.5 and MariaDB 10.3.11 (MySQL 8.x)

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5?

Comment: if you remove the unique keys, it works. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=495f27481a9974275f7f8372589ec9e2

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Why should the keys cause this error? Looks more like a bug.

Comment: When you enforce the uniqueness of the two columns in a pair, the update changes the value, but the pair is not automatically updated because the cascade goes one by one, that is why you got the error in the second fk. Once the first update is done, the cascade changes the value, but after that change the fk2 is being raised. I believe it is how it works internally, whether this is a bug or not, well it is not up to me.

Comment: check that with one unique key without pair, it works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=8cc41873c6a1c7d41b94a5a44ee28794

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Thanks for the response, but I don't get it how this should break uniqueness. update from 1 -> 10, orig. (and only)  mapping (1,1), first cascade -> (10,1) (is unique!) -> second cascade (10,10) (is unique!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a bug or intended behavior.

As a workaround, if your version of MySql is 8.0.13+, which supports [Functional Key Parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts), you can use 1 `UNIQUE KEY` (to check the uniqueness of the combination of the 2 columns) instead of the 2 keys and the `UPDATE` statement will work:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_map (
map_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_a INT,
user_b INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`map_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY unk_users((LEAST(`user_a`,`user_b`)), (GREATEST(`user_a`,`user_b`))),
  CONSTRAINT `acc_connections_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_a`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `acc_connections_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_b`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6b95a57621093b8178fb56d44fc74ac).

Comment: Sadly I cannot use 8.0.13 cause the existing infrastrucuture makes this (hopefully just currently...) impossible.